# ORDER BY with IF...ELSE SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a very basic problem that I'm trying to solve (basic to me, anyway), but I'm having trouble understanding why one bit of code works standalone, but when you wrap it in an IF statement, it doesn't.

This works just fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.FB FROM I_HSE H WHERE H.AC IN (@AC) ORDER BY H.FB
```

However, when I try to make use of it in an IF statement:

```
IF @FILTERBY = '2'
  BEGIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT H.FB FROM I_HSE H WHERE H.AC IN (@AC) ORDER BY H.FB)
  END
```

I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

I've done some searching, but I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work.  Is there another way to order the returned result set?

Comment: What is in @AC? I don't think this is going to work the way you think it does.

Comment: As noted, the first example works just fine.  @AC is an integer, and this is intended to accept values from an SSRS report.

Comment: Ok, we'll then why is it IN instead of =? If you pass a string like '12,15,18' it is not going to work unless you are constructing it dynamically.

Comment: In this specific case, you are correct that = would be better, as for this piece, I will never be passing more than one value.  I've just gotten used to using `IN (@AC)` in most of my SSRS reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the parenthesis off

Like so:

```
IF @FILTERBY = '2'
  BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT H.FB FROM I_HSE H WHERE H.AC IN (@AC) ORDER BY H.FB
  END
```

Comment: I'll admit, I feel a bit like an idiot now.  I should've tried that first.  In my defense, every example I found had the select surrounded by ( ).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ( and ):

```
IF @FILTERBY = '2'
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT H.FB FROM I_HSE H WHERE H.AC IN (@AC) ORDER BY H.FB
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Revove the parenthesis around your SELECT